# Difference with glmnet (LASSO regression case)

Tags: r, glmnet, lasso-regression

I am currently trying to reproduce the results of glmnet (in the LASSO regression case) myself and I notice differences in the results I get and those given by glmnet that I can't explain.

Not being an expert in Fortran, I relied on the following post to code: [https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/glmnet.pdf](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Ehastie/Papers/glmnet.pdf)

I attach a part of my code so that you can see what I am talking about.

```
soft <- function(a, lambda){
  
  # calculate new beta
  new_beta = sign(a) * max(abs(a) - lambda, 0)
  
  return(new_beta)
  
}

lasso <- function(Xtilde, Ytilde, beta, lambda){
  
  return((crossprod(Ytilde - Xtilde %*% beta)) /(2 * length(Ytilde)) + lambda * sum(abs(beta)))
  
}

LASSOstandardized <- function(Xtilde, Ytilde, lambda, eps, beta_start = NULL){

  #Coordinate-descent implementation
  beta_last = beta_start
  beta_new = beta_start
  r = Ytilde - Xtilde %*% beta_last
  
  repeat {
    beta_last = beta_new
    for (i in 1:ncol(Xtilde)) {
      beta_new[i] = soft((beta_last[i] + crossprod(r, Xtilde[, i])/nrow(Xtilde)), lambda )
      r = r + Xtilde[, i] * (beta_last[i] - beta_new[i])
    }
    
    loss_old = lasso(Xtilde, Ytilde, beta_last, lambda)
    loss_new = lasso(Xtilde, Ytilde, beta_new, lambda)
    loss_diff = loss_old - loss_new
    
    if (abs(loss_diff) < eps){
      break
    }
    
  }
  return(beta_new)
}
```

Here is an example to visualize the differences in results I am talking about.

```
library(ISLR)
Hitters=na.omit(Hitters)[1:259,c(1:13,19)]
x=model.matrix(Salary~.-1,data=Hitters) 
y=Hitters$Salary
LASSOstandardized(x,y,2,0.0000001)
glmnet(x,y, alpha=1,lambda=2)$beta
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Cannot reproduce using your code: ``> LASSOstandardized(x,y,2)
Error in Xtilde %*% beta_last : 
  requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments``

Comment: Thank you for your remark. It's good I modified.